# Setting parent div background color/image on hover (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, background

I'm having issues changing the background of a parent div when I hover over certain child elements. I'm trying to use the first child div `'.pro1'`  to change the background color of the parent container `'.projectbkg'` and I'm not entirely sure of the jQuery I'm using.

I've tried variations but nothing seems to work, I will be using this with background images as well as background color's but I'm trying to get the jQuery working before replacing the colors with images.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div class="projectbkg">
<div class="projecttabs">
<div class="prohead">
<div class="pro1"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-701" src="https://vanst.one/content/2017/06/PS-Icon.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" /></div>
<div class="pro2"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-1857" src="https://vanst.one/content/2017/06/ai_cc_app_RGB.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" /></div>
<div class="pro3"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-710" src="https://vanst.one/content/2017/06/MC-Icon.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" /></div>
<div class="pro4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-709" src="https://vanst.one/content/2017/06/INF-Icon.png" alt="" width="75" height="75" /></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* PROJECT PANEL CSS */
.prohead {
    height: 700px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-right: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
.projectbkg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}
.projecttabs {
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.pro1, .pro2, .pro3, .pro4 {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s;
    border-top: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
}
.pro1:hover, .pro2:hover, .pro3:hover, .pro4:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s;
    -o-transition: 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: 0.3s;
}
/* END PROJECT PANEL CSS */
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".pro1").hover(function(){
    jQuery(".projectbkg").css("background-color", "#f0f0f0");
    }, function(){
    jQuery(".projectbkg").css("background-color", "#000");
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:**

In [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m779oju8/), hovering over the Photoshop Logo should trigger a change to the `'.projectbkg'`'s background property. Any help with this would be appreciated!

**WORKING FIDDLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/5p3qoe8b/1/

Comment: Unrelated to your question but why don't you add another class to your html elements and clean up the css instead of selecting the class `.pro1, .pro2`ect you can just select a single class, it'll make it look alot cleaner

Comment: @JackRogers thanks for the suggestion :) all the elements need their own classes for individual functions but I might group them with a second parent class

Answer (score 3):

This: `jQuery(.projectbkg)` is invalid syntax, you'll have to quote the CSS selector `jQuery(".projectbkg")`

Comment: Updated the fiddle but it still doesn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: @van you haven't added the jQuery library to your fiddle.